# How to create layout for listing tags, with the ability to click on specific ones and delete

Tags: android, android-layout, google-plus

I am looking to create something very similar to what Google has done in the Google+ app.

Its hard to describe but please take a look at this screenshot

[Google+ app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMfKW.jpg)

I am looking to create something similar, of note is that the tags move to the proper line as they fit.

Is this a completely custom solution that Google wrote or is there a library for this somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like they are decorating the text in the edit text by using spans.  They probably have a listener on the edit text listening for modifications at which point they check to see if the most recently added word matches one of your circles. If it does, the create a span over the text and decorate it with a background drawable, font color change, and by adding an image next to it.

Its probably a pretty significant effort depending on how you want to function, but all that functionality is out there in the sdk.

Comment: But they also have the ability to delete specific circles/tags just by touching them.  Currently trying to implement this usign some sort of internal linking system.

Comment: Spans have this ability too. If you look at how the URLSpan is implemented you can see how ClickableSpans are enabled.